# Rebuild index menu not available in SSMS for Azure SQL database

Tags: azure-sql-database, ssms

Connected to Azure SQL Database from SSMS. The versions are (1) Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8 (2) SSMS 18.11.1

Rebuild index menu option not available when right click index folder level or individual index level. The snapshots are attached. What is missing ?

(1) Folder level
[image]

(2) Index level
[image]

Comment: It appears that feature isn't available via SSMS dialogue windows; use T-SQL instead.

Comment: I tried that option also, alter index <Index_name> on <table_name> rebuild, but it seems this is also not working because the index fragmentation is not solved after running alter index

Comment: And what happened?

Comment: index fragmentation issue not resolved after running alter index

Comment: OK, so it sounds like that is your *real* problem here. Though why your rebuild is failing is a question for [dba.se].

Comment: Shall i post different question with tag to DBA

Comment: I would, personally, suggest that yes you post a *new* qusetion on [dba.se] about the error you are getting when trying to run the `REBUILD` in T-SQL, ***after*** looking for duplicates and researching the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created SQL database in Azure portal.
Image for reference:

[image]

I login in MSSM using Azure SQL server credentials.

Image for reference:

[image]

I connected to Azure SQL database in MSSM successfully.

Image for reference:

[image]

I also didn't get option of rebuild index
Image for reference:

[image]

I used below query to check the list of the indexes in the database, with the most fragmented first.

```
SELECT
OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(ips.OBJECT_ID) 'Schema',
OBJECT_NAME(ips.OBJECT_ID) 'Table',
i.NAME,
ips.index_id,
index_type_desc,
avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
avg_page_space_used_in_percent,
page_count
FROM
sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, 'SAMPLED') ips
INNER JOIN
sys.indexes i
ON (ips.object_id = i.object_id)
AND
(
ips.index_id = i.index_id
)
ORDER BY
avg_fragmentation_in_percent DESC
```

I got the output as below:

[image]

I rebuild index of TestTable using below code:

```
ALTER INDEX <indexName> ON <TableName> REBUILD  WITH (ONLINE = ON)
```

Output:

[image]

It worked successfully in my machine please check from your end.